# Building an android project fails with Internal Error

Tags: java, android

I opened a project I last built a year ago on a different machine, and I get an odd Internal Error

> `Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index`

This is Android Studio, latest version

Any ideas gratefully received!

Comment: Check your imports. If all imports are added, build a clean project.

Comment: Thanks for this idea

Answer (score 0):

I found copying the source to a new folder, and opening THAT in Android Studio started a bunch of gradle downloads/updates, which got me going again.
Not sure what the issue was, but this might help someone else.